# How many elements are in the following set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fractions, rational-numbers

The set is
$$\{ x \in Q:x^2 =64/25 \} $$

I thought the answer was $\{ \frac{8}{5}, -\frac{8}{5} \}$ but I am told there are in fact 4 distinct elements:

$$\{ \frac{8}{5}, \frac{8}{-5}, \frac{-8}{5}, \frac{-8}{-5},  \}$$

So are there 2 elements in the set or 4?

Comment: Unless the question is worded strangely, your answer was right. The second and fourth elements there are usually omitted in every form of arithmetic I've ever used (since they're equivalent).

Comment: What is $Q$? Just the set of rational numbers? It it's some kind of set $\{(a, b): a, b \in \Bbb Z\}$ and each pair gets identified with a sort of formal fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ but without the equivalence relation we put on $\Bbb Q$, then I could see $4$ elements.

Comment: Q is $\mathbb{Q}$